# C++17: Does the 'value computation' of an int& glvalue involve 'using the value of the object'?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

## The Problem

The C++17 standard specifies in `[intro.execution]/17` that it is undefined behavior if you have a
`side effect on a memory location` unsequenced with a `value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location`.

I am currently trying to trace a `-Wsequence-point` warning emitted by GCC and I assume that this is
what's happening here, though I don't know if I read the standard right.

This is an example of the code that makes GCC 5 to 12 emit the warning<sup>1</sup>:

```
struct Int {
        int x;
};

int main()
{
        Int i{0};
        i = i = Int{1};

        // This is the same, but it's easier to talk about this:
        i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}));
}
```

The warning is:

```
<source>:9:7: warning: operation on '* & i' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
        9 |     i = i = Int{1};
            |     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

([See here at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEElykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CIWGRLDFxAXaYDulCBEzEBJk%2BfuWY9vkMNXUEhRHRsfG2tfWN2QkKQ92hvSX9ZgCUtqhexMjsHCYaAILjxF4OANQAkoL7JgDsVlv71/uhBPuqJgDMl5vnACLPrxubd/ssTFCEDmP3OrxuRxOeDBGg%2BXx%2BELwpye71uyNRxwIYK4cJeCJueAAdKhErEmERiM93hAiSSyRSqRBMdiPnMQXith8OAtaJwAKy8PwcLSkVCcNzWaz7BRLFaYU5mJ48UgETTchYAaxAfK4hKefIAnE9jWcNFwzAAOE36TiSQVq0WcXgKEAaFVqhZwWAwRAgTCqSpeCnkSh1YAKZSGVpCBCoADuQuVaBYiTo5PSkbCtBj8aFIuTqfocWA5oCBbosQA8kGcwmHf7KptiOGnYEA8gavghbx%2BIIRGJ2FIZIJFCp1MKdHoDEYUJLLPo8FEXZAFiT2i6OABaADqYlo%2B03m/G6Cppks1i4Z2dstWemPoUz0djde4vAIxEwa2VceITESnB4Hl%2BXtCdHQ4bB2yDEgHgtAA2TdYMkfZgGQZB9nNQkzH2CAJXPed9lwQhoPMJU5jfD1NRASRYMJA1JCkA0DUvMwuHNSRpF5Dg7VIFh/A0QlYKVDQ%2BRYkSzieDQNDOC1SDzXgxQ4Z1XXdCdPR9CAkAbZAoLICgIDDCMo2zZ9E14csDHaR9jNzB1zP6YAdTdOziGrYQTPrdsmxbRS20qTtQlbXthFEcQhyC0c1AdXQAmnYw5xsWhF2XYFRUSddOB3PcDyPAgTxRM8rEsS9r2WW8xlyh8jNrUyVQ/L9eB/P8AO5G0OAFWSHQUiDAwpGD4MQ5DUP2PlCS4bDcMKmwCPwXqSK4MiVK0NlSAQTAmCwOIUs47jeLMfizlYi1Lw0WCzgOp44I60CFKUt1VVU0gvV9LSdJDfTm0MrNqua0hzPTAQrO%2B0DnJQWKuD5STftQFMKxcmt3NArSvI3XgtP87th2CgcJGkcKlEi0DdCefRDDivCEqS%2BBVzS9IN0y2h90PY9T3i4rFlKwdBi7QGEeVd9Px%2Bxr/1fIC2pAkUusg3rVDghCkOQWL0JG/iNHG%2BLSGmojiAVUjyNUhZVvW/otttXhdv4rhYI0A0NAtMxpLORC4JkuSwNuxaWqejS/Slkg3oMnmbNfKGYYsjMqoR/NocLfoADdkESRIAH1Y64A0k4szBxiT1REJDmO4bcoORSRj7WzRiqMaC/tQtx2QIvHEVdA40nZ3Jhclyp1L0o4AB6Y828my99l77duJlDm70rwOXz5urBd/YXANa9rXclnroNzpCWAUeP9lTg1CUz8Y1fbzXZsVea9aWg21o2yhRZ2kALsJSQDVgsxP4hqSmK4C1pDXq2F0d0KKkC1JIC0AlJAnVgh/A0FoDqwI4pwJ44t5KtnujfVqZg0Fuw9stWOsRUjOEkEAA))

Clang and MSVC don't warn about this. I'm trying to verify what happens here. You can see my
detailled, rather tedious analysis below, but here's what I think I found:

In `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}));`, the outer `operator=` evaluates two expressions: `i` (its
left-hand-side operand) and `i.operator=(Int{1})` (the right-hand side). I think that the
value-computation part of evaluating `i`<sup>2</sup> is unsequenced
relative to the side-effect part of `i.operator=(Int{1})`<sup>3</sup>.

However, that would only be UB if the value-computation of the expression `i` is, in the words of
the standard, `a value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location`. Since
`i` is a local variable, the expression `i` is a `glvalue`, and its value-computation should only
compute its *identity*, not its *value*, according to `[basic.lval]/1.1`:

> - A glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function.

So I would argue that the value-computation of `i` in this case does not `use the value of any object […]` — but then I don't see why GCC emits the warning.

So: Is my assumption wrong? Is it the value-computation of `i` and the side-effect of
`i.operator=(Int{1})` that clash here?

## Detailled Analysis

Here I'll try to list all side-effects and value-computations (I'll call both 'events' from now on)
that happen during evaluation of `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}));`, show the standard rules that
govern their sequencing and analyze which pairs of potentially problematic events are sequenced how.

### All events

As far as I can see, ten events are happening here (not necessarily in this order):

- ****Av**** Value-computation for `Int{1}`
- ****As**** Side-effects for the `Int{1}`
- ****Bv**** Value-computation for the first operand of `i.operator=(Int{1}))`, i.e., `i`
- ****Bs**** Side-effects for for the first operand of `i.operator=(Int{1}))`, i.e., `i`
- ****Cv**** Value-computation for the expression `i.operator=(Int{1}))`
- ****Cs**** Side-effects for the expression `i.operator=(Int{1}))`
- ****Dv**** Value-computation for the first operand of `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}))`, i.e., `i`
- ****Ds**** Side-Effects for the first operand of `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}))`, i.e., `i`
- ****Ev**** Value-computation for `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}))`
- ****Es**** Side-effects for `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}))`

There are [two things](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior) that can lead to UB in this context:

- Two unsequenced side-effects "on the same object"

  - In this example: ****Es**** and ****Cs**** being unsequenced (all other side-effects are "empty")
- An usequenced value-computation "using the value of the object" and side-effect "on the same object"

  - In this example: Any of ****Cs**** or ****Es**** being unsequenced vs any of ****Bv****, ****Cv****, ****Dv**** or ****Ev****.

The standard has [many rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules) on what is sequenced after what, but I think the relevant rules here are (paraphrasing, ordering arbitrary):

- ****Rule 1****: The value-computation (**not** the side-effects!) of operands are sequenced before the value-computation (**not** the side-effect!) of the operator
- ****Rule 2a****: The side effect (modification of the left argument) of the built-in assignment operator […] is sequenced after the value computation (but not the side effects) of both left and right arguments,
- ****Rule 2b****: The side effect (modification of the left argument) of the built-in assignment operator […] is sequenced before the value computation of the assignment expression (that is, before returning the reference to the modified object)

With that, we get:

- ****(I)**** Rule 1 gives us ****(Av, Bv) => Cv**** (read: ****Av**** and ****Bv**** are sequenced before ****Cv****), and ****(Cv, Dv) => Ev****.
- ****(II)**** Rule 2a gives us ****(Av, Bv) => Cs**** and ****(Cv, Dv) => Es****
- ****(III)**** Rule 2b gives us ****Cs => Cv**** and ****Es => Ev****

Combining ****Cv => Es**** from ****(II)**** and ****Cs => Cv**** from ****(III)****, we get ****Cs => Es****, so we can rule out the "unsequenced side-effects" UB possibility from above.

Let's check if ****Cs**** can be unsequenced vs either of ****Bv****, ****Cv****, ****Dv**** or ****Ev****:

- ****(II)**** rules out ****Bv****
- ****(III)**** rules out ****Cv****
- ****(II) + (III)**** gives us ****Cs => Cv => Es => Ev****, thereby ruling out ****Ev****
- I cannot find a chain from ****Cs**** to ****Dv****!.

Finally, let's check if ****Es**** can be unsequenced vs either of ****Bv****, ****Cv****, ****Dv**** or ****Ev****:

- ****(II)**** rules out ****Dv**** and ****Cv****
- ******(III)****** rules out ****Ev****
- ****(I) + (II)**** give us ****Bv => Cv => Es****, thus ruling out ****Bv****

Only ****Dv**** vs ****Cs**** remains as a potentially unsequenced pair!

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Note that I could have just used int instead of my wrapped-int Int. However, then I could not have made the .operator=() calls explicit.

<sup>2</sup> Denoted Dv in the analysis below

<sup>3</sup> Denoted Cs in the example below

Comment: I think that the two expressions are not equivalent. The sequencing is different: In the explicit form, the `i` in `i.operator=` is evaluated before the function argument. In the implicit form the expressions on the right side of `=` are evaluated before the expression on the left side despite the fact that both are ultimately arguments of a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answer considers only C++11 and later. It may be different for pre-C++11.)

> This is an example of the code that makes GCC 5 to 12 emit the warning

The warning is a false positive. The behavior will never be undefined.

```
// This is the same, but it's easier to talk about this:
i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}));
```

The sequencing rules for function calls are not the same as those for operators, so that is a risky simplification.

> Note that I could have just used int instead of my wrapped-int Int. However, then I could not have made the .operator=() calls explicit.

The rules are also different if calls to a function are involved (directly or indirectly) rather than direct access to a scalar. So again this is a risky change.

> I think that the value-computation part of evaluating i is unsequenced relative to the side-effect part of i.operator=(Int{1}).

Since C++17 the left-hand `i.operator=` naming the function is sequenced (including all side-effects) before all argument expressions (i.e. `i.operator=(Int{1})`). (rule 14 at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order))

A side effect can only exist on a scalar object. The side effect of `i.operator=(Int{1})` is on the scalar object `i.x` and happens not immediately in the expression, but inside the function call. All evaluations part of a function call are *indeterminately sequenced* with all other evaluations in the caller if they are not otherwise sequenced. (rule 11 at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order))

Therefore before C++17 it would still not be unsequenced. It would just be unspecified which of the two is evaluated first.

This is already one reason that the GCC warning is bogus.

> So I would argue that the value-computation of i in this case does not use the value of any object […] — but then I don't see why GCC emits the warning.

Yes, that is also true and a second reason that the warning is
bogus.

---

In your detailed analysis the listed rules 1 applies only to `i = i = Int{1};`, not to `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}));`, because the latter isn't using any `=` operator, just function calls.

Rules 2a and 2b don't apply at all, because you are not using a built-in assignment operator. You are in either case calling (explicitly or implicitly) a `operator=` overload. The overload is *implicitly-defined*, but that doesn't make it *builtin*. The builtin assignment operators are the ones that apply directly to scalar types without a function call.

Even if you had not wrapped the `int` in a `struct`, so that you really are using a builtin assignment in `i = i = Int{1};`, these would be the pre-C++17 rules.

Since C++17 there is another sequencing rule that guarantees that the right-hand side of the assignment is sequenced before the left-hand one, including all side-effects. (rule 20 at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order))

Note that this is reversed from the ordering I mentioned above for `i.operator=(i.operator=(Int{1}))` since C++17!

The relevant rules are those for function calls which you are not considering. In particular the rule for indeterminate sequencing with respect to bodies of called functions is missing.

---

If you had not wrapped the `int` in a `struct` and used `i = i = int(1);`, then it would still not be undefined, even before C++17. In this case the rules you listed, paired with the evaluation of the `i` glvalue not counting itself as an access to `i`, will show that there is no violation of the sequencing rules as well. (Admittedly I didn't go through your deduction to check whether it is showing this.)

Comment: You are of course right - rewriting `i = i = 1` into the `i.operator=(i.operator=(1))` changes the applicable rules because of the function call. My bad, I just found it a lot easier to write about, since otherwise you always just end up with an `i`. 
Just to make sure I understand you correctly: In the `i = i = 1` case (where we don't have the sequencing from the function calls), what saves us from UB is indeed the fact that the glvalue evaluation does not "use the value of the object", right?

Comment: @LukasBarth Yes, before C++17. The left-hand `i` evaluation and the side effect on `i` from `i = 1` are unsequenced before C++17, but evaluation of `i` without an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion doesn't read or use `i`'s value in any way. Since C++17 rule 20 from cppreference applies and they are not unsequenced at all. In this case whether or not evaluation of `i` uses its value is irrelevant.

Comment: Before C++17, the unwrapped case `i = i = 1` is undefined, because there are two side effects on `i` and they are unsequenced.

Comment: @j6t The side effect of the left-hand `=` is for obvious reasons sequenced after the value computation of `i = 1` and since C++11 the assignment's side effect is sequenced before its value computation. See [\[expr.ass\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ass#1) and also rule 2b as in the question. So the side effect of the left-hand `=` is sequenced after that of the right-hand side.